# Using NSPredicate to filter out array of strings from NSManagedObject set property

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Let's assume I have a `NSArray` of `NSManagedObject` objects (fetched from Core Data) of type `Game` and a second object `Genre` which only has one property `name`.

```
let games: [Game] = []

class Game: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var genres: NSOrderedSet?
    @NSManaged public var publishers: NSOrderedSet?
    @NSManaged public var tags: NSOrderedSet?
}

class Genre: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
}

let genres: Set<String> = ["Racing", "Strategy", "Fighting"]
```

Assuming I have a `Set` of genres like above, how to use `NSPredicate` to filter out games from the array, where at least one genre from the set matches the tags in any game. Or should I just do a typical for loop?

Comment: I'm confused. Is the "Set of genres like above" the set `var genres: NSOrderedSet?`? Do you want to filter the games where at least one genre of the game matches any tag of any game?

Comment: @Willeke I have Game entity with a to-many relationship with Genre entity. I want to filter out games that match any genre from the array of strings. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes, the tags and genres are mixed up. Please edit the question and remove all tags (the word "tag" in the question, not the tags of the question).

Comment: @Willeke right, fixed :)

Comment: Try predicate `NSPredicate(format: "ANY genres.name in %@", genres)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSPredicate`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY genres IN %@", genres)
```

Using `filter`

```
let filtered = games.filter {
    !$0.genres.intersection(genres).isEmpty
}
```

Comment: how can it work when Genre is an object of type NSManagedObject with a property of type String name? Also genres inside Game entity is of type NSManagedSet? so in both cases they need to be unwrapped.